# finding index in a nested list

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [efficient word indexing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852043/efficient-word-indexing-in-python)

Apologies for the basic question, how can I find the indexes `((1,2),(2,1),(2,2))` corresponding to "yellow" in `ref` and store them so that I can access them afterwords without rerunning the search?

```
ref1 = "this is a test" 
ref2 = "this is a yellow test"
ref3 = "this is yellow"
ref4 = "yellow and orange are colors"
ref = ((ref1,ref2),(ref3,ref4))
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also, why is it tagged list? There are no lists anywhere in your question. Those are tuples.

Comment: David, it is often considered an affront to those of us to care about the community to post something which was just closed under a different name.

Comment: Sorry, I am new, I did not understand why it was closed before, and I was just trying to change the question

Comment: David, you are welcome to edit and clarify your question. If you usefully revise your question, downvotes will be reversed, the question will be re-opened, and answers will come quickly.

Comment: This should not be closed.  The "duplicate" was closed because there was not a question in it (although a question was added in an edit).  This may have the same content but it is not a duplicate because it actually contains a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of it:

```
[(k,i) for k,m in enumerate(ref, 1) for i,j in enumerate(m, 1) if 'yellow' in j]
```

but you probably want the real index (starting at zero)... Remove the second argument of `enumerate` if so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to generate a list of pairs from a list (or tuple) of nested lists (or tuples) for every time you see the word 'yellow' then:

```
answer = []
for i in range(len(ref)):
    nested_tuple = ref[i]
    for j in range(len(nested_tuple)):
        string = ref[i][j]
        if string.find('yellow') != -1: answer.append((i,j))
```